# pip install private package from local with external dependency

Tags: python, pip

I am using pip to install a few private packages in a virtual environment.
Using python version 3.7.3 and pip version 18.1

I have copied the .whl file of that private package to a local directory.
Now that package has external dependencies whith another private packages and also public packages.

By Public Package I meant the package that is available from public repositories (pypi or piwheels).

I have tried using

```
pip install my-private-package -f /path/to/private/package/directory
```

Now, this is failing with below message:

```
Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: 404 Client Error: Not Found for url: https://pypi.org/simple/my_private_package
```

Then I have tried below two command (expecting this would fail)

```
pip install -f /path/to/private/package/directory --no-index
```

and

```
pip install --no-index --find-links=/path/to/private/package/directory private-package  --extra-index-url https://pypi.org/simple --extra-index-url  https://www.piwheels.org/simple
```

and those failed as expected with same error message

```
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement public-package==x.x.x (from private-package->another-private-package) (from versions: )
```

I also tried

```
pip install /path/to/private/package/directory/private_package_x_x_x.whl
```

This failed too with below error message. Which means that another private package could not be found in public repository. This is obvious.

```
Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: 404 Client Error: Not Found for url: https://pypi.org/simple/another-private-package/
```

So the last attempt that was tried:

```
pip install /path/to/private/package/directory/private_package_x_x_x.whl --find-links=/path/to/private/package/directory
```

Unfortunately, no luck this time too.

I can think of a couple of workarounds:

1. Download all the dependencies and keep it in the local directory (/path/to/private/package/directory)
2. Create a private server and provide index information over http

Now, not happy with option 1 as I have to download every time a new public dependency is added. Option 2 may be a good option - I may go with it, if no other option is found.

Any input suggestion will be greatly appreciated.

### Update:

OS: debian 10 python version 3.7.3 and pip version 18.1

> This works on Windows with python 3.9 and PIP 21.1.2 , i.e pip install
> my-private-package -f C:\path\to\private\package\directory

Comment: `pip install <path>` should work... Are you sure it is not a problem with dependencies? Try installing a private package that only has public dependencies this way

Comment: alright this seems to be working.
So I need to install all private packages with all public dependencies first

Comment: I would guess so... Another solution is to make wheels for your private packages and then install everything but adding the wheels directory. Something like `pip install --find-links /path/to/wheels/dir/ -r requirements.txt`

Comment: yeh.. I guess, I know what you mean. This is another option to consider.
I wish there is any magic option in pip that checks for dependencies in both the locations, i.e. --find-links and the public repositories. :)

Comment: It does! if you specify `--find-links` it still checks the public index as well

Comment: well it was failing for me somehow until I used the requirement.txt
If it does, now, I am curious to find out what was wrong. I'll check that later and update

Comment: The earlier answer I have added was completely wrong. I tried to setup a fresh environment and it didn't work. So finally, I realised that whatever you said works but the problem was the version..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the direction [@Matteo Zanoni](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13384774/matteo-zanoni).
The problem was the version. The --find-link works when I upgraded pip from 18.1 to 21.3.1